# Mosfet Selection

Tags: batteries, mosfet, cell-balancing

I am designing  Battery balance system for 16 series Lion(NCR18650) battery pack.I have decided to implement passive balance method.Battery cell voltages will be controlled by MCU and whenever a difference occurs a mosfet which connected parallel to battery cell will be triggered.I have chosen FDN327N as mosfet.But I am not sure if this mosfet can be driven by 3.3V output. can you guys say if selected mosfet can be triggered  by 3.3V. Here is my circuit

[image]

Comment: If you connect 16 batteries in series like that, you'll exceed all sorts of maximum ratings for that MOSFET. Besides, you'd need to level shift the gate voltages as they're relative to the source pins.

Comment: The LTC3300 will balance up to 6 batteries per IC, 36 volt limit. They can be stacked and put under control of a common LTC680x battery monitor.

Comment: Finbarr can a optical mosfet driver solve this issue? Cause it will separate vgs from the system

Comment: Sparky256 I know LTC680xx series or BQ76PL455 will do the-self balance ,but as a student I wanna understand and experince BMS building by myself